# How to implement a overlapping TextView in a ImageView, which combinely works as a Button?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, button, textview, imageview

I am new to Android development and I need to know if I can overlap an imageView and a TextView together into a button. It should be similar to the image that I've shared and I need to frame it in a GridLayout with 2 columns. If I use FrameLayout for each imageView and textView it becomes little complex, is there any alternative method?

[image: sample image]

Comment: What have you tried for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: combining text & image on a Button or ImageButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532876/android-combining-text-image-on-a-button-or-imagebutton)

Comment: You can use FrameLayout to put a View over Another [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679369/what-does-framelayout-do)

Comment: @RumitPatel I've tried using FrameLayout

Comment: Use _RelativeLayout_, _FrameLayout_ or _ConstrainLayout_

Comment: @Piyush Will try. Thanks!

Comment: You can do it with Relativelayout

Comment: @Maitri Yeah! Tried it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this and run...if any error occurs please tell me I will help

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Button
            android:id="@+id/img_category"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/your_image"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBlack"
            android:text="Title"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

</GridLayout>
```

Comment: But I need it in a GridLayout and it should be a button!

Comment: Check my edited answer. You can customize it according to your requirements @HarishV

Comment: Thank you for this!