# Purpose of FrameLayout?

Tags: android, android-framelayout

All examples I find for `FrameLayout` use the `FrameLayout` to stack multiple children on top of each other. Even e.g. Stackoverflow answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679369/what-does-framelayout-do) says

> You use a FrameLayout to stack child views on top of each other,

The [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout) however states

> FrameLayout is designed to block out an area on the screen to display a **single item**. Generally, FrameLayout should be used to hold a **single child view**,

While adding multiple children to it is possible, it sounds like it's just a side effect.

So, what's the originally intended use case for a FrameLayout with a **single** item? Anyone has an example for that?

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25679369/what-does-framelayout-do

Comment: It's the simplest layout possible, it lays out each child view based only on its size and gravity disregarding other children which creates the effect of view stacking on top.

Comment: Elias, I cant find an example with a SINGLE child in the linked topic ): Pawel, thanks I am aware of this yet wondering what's the use case for a single child.

Answer (score 0):

There are different purposes why `FrameLayout` with only one child can be useful. Imagine having a loading spinner that should be centered but not fill the whole page but also you want the content to be hidden when the loading spinner is shown. Possible solution: `FrameLayout` with `match_parent` for width and height and a background color and the `ProgressBar` (Loading spinner) with `android:layout_gravity=center` as only child of the `FrameLayout`. So now you can set the `android:visibility` of the `FrameLayout` to show or hide the whole thing.

Comment: hmm but how would I place the Frame Layout with the spinner on top of the content Layout, e.g. a LinearLayout?

Comment: The parent component needs to be a view that supports that, so for example you could use a FrameLayout as well and then embed your real content into a LinearLayout that is direct child of the FrameLayout and uses the complete width. But you could also use a ConstraintLayout. Many possibilities here...

Comment: So you mean FrameLayoutA -> LinearLayout (for content) | FrameLayoutB (for spinner). In this case FrameLayoutA has to children, but I care about examples for FrameLayouts with one children. FrameLayoutB has only one children (the spinner), but I don't see the necessity to use a FrameLayoutB for the spinner - couldn't this just also be e.g. a LinearLayout? So there is still no real use case for a FrameLayout with only one children, while the documentation seems to state that this (only a single children) is the intended use case for a FrameLayout?

Comment: Afaik having only one children inside of a LinearLayout to then position it centered is not the supposed functionality of LinearLayout. I don't know if it has a big effect on performance but if you consider having one child inside of a LinearLayout with full width and height to then make the child be centered you better use a FrameLayout.